# Where to build new domain entities? Controller, repository, or mapper?

Tags: php, instantiation, separation-of-concerns

Let's say for each domain entity, I have a repository that provides an API to a data mapper. For example, if I have a UserEntity, then I would have a UserRepository that speaks to a UserMapper to persist user data in a database.

Now, let's say a form is submitted on a web page, and my controller knows it needs to create a new UserEntity based on the submitted info.

Does it:

1. do new UserEntity() right there on the spot, and run all the necessary setter methods according to the form data submitted, then pass the UserEntity to the repo, who passes to the mapper for insertion?

   Controller creates UserEntity => Repo => Mapper => DB
2. turn the form data into an array, and pass it to the UserRepository who then runs new UserEntity() and the setters, and passes it to the mapper for insertion?

   Controller passes user data => Repo creates UserEntity => Mapper => DB
3. pass the array to the UserRepository, who passes the array to the mapper for new UserEntity and insertion?

   Controller passes user data => Repo passes user data => Mapper creates UserEntity => DB

Whose responsibility is it to manage the creation of objects?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but I thought I'd throw my thoughts in here since the only answer hasn't been officially accepted and this may be helpful to future searchers.  To directly answer your question, I'd say none of the above.  I prefer to have an extra service, a "manager" if you will, for brokering the interaction between the controller and the repo/mapper objects.  Each model has a dedicated manager for handling its creation, updates, and deletion.

**Controllers**

I consider the controller as the glue of the application.  We can separate concerns all we want into as many pieces as possible, but somewhere along the line, something has to understand both the view side and the model side, and that object is the controller.  That being said, I believe controllers should be skinny, so the controller's only real job is to map a request to a response.  Any kind of intermediate processing should be kicked off somewhere else.

In a CRUD app, it's pretty easy to get away with instantiating new objects and persisting them in the controller, even it is done more than once, because it is only a few lines to paste.  What if object creation was not trivial?  I'm maintaining an application with many complex relationships and a user-submitted create often entails the creation of many objects simultaneously.  This is not feasible to maintain in a controller-and-model-only environment.

**Extra Service Layers**

To handle this, I've created 2 extra service layers: FormHandler and Manager.  Every time a form is submitted, the form contents get sent to the form handler layer.  Form handlers are responsible for understanding the form data coming in and normalizing it.  The form handlers can then pass off the data to appropriate manager objects for processing.  Manager objects process the data and update the domain layer.  They are responsible for creating models, changing models, and persisting them to the backend.

In this way, the controllers have knowledge of Request, Response, Form (possibly, if your framework supports server-side form creation), and FormHandler.  Form handlers have knowledge of Form (or form data), and Manager.  Manager has knowledge of Repository, Mapper, and Model.  Notice, now, Managers are the sole point of interaction with Models and the Mapper, and they have no knowledge of the Form data or the Request or Response.  On the flip side, the controllers and form handlers don't need to know about domain layer data or persistence.

**Conclusion**

With this design:

`Controller -> FormHandler -> ModelManager -> Mapper`

I've found all my classes are now unit-testable (even controllers to some degree) due to separation of concerns being nicely split out, and the single point of interaction is a boon for avoiding duplicate logic.

**Notes**

The repo in my mind is only for querying the database -- asking it if it has something, not creating new things.

My experience in this case is from using Symfony 2 and Doctrine 2.

YMMV; e.g. you may find the form layer is unnecessary, but I've found it very handy for data transformation from form/view data into something the domain models understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough question to answer.  My two cents are on number 1 for a couple of reasons.  First, it's assumed you have domain validation in your entity which could very well reject the  data being passed.  If that were to happen in either 2 or 3 then you've gone a few objects deep before the rejection.  It may not be a lot of memory or execution time in terms of the difference between 2/3 and 1, but it is a difference.  I try to fail fast.

Second, I think the controller knowing about the data being passed in as well as the objects is entirely acceptable.  I agree with "fat model, skinny controller" but saying the controller can't know about the entities is making the controller **too** skinny for my liking.

Comment: That's a great analysis of the situation. I'm curious to hear other thoughts, but I certainly think is acceptable to create it in the Controller. However, maybe less flexibility? For example, if I add a new field to the User table in the DB, I then have to remember to go to each Controller that creates UserEntities.

Comment: You'll most likely be editing the view that accepts said new information (assuming we're talking about a traditional web application), editing the controller isn't too much of a stretch.  Chances are if you forgot to edit the controller you forgot to edit the view.  Besides, a simple global search can find where your class is used.

Comment: Another good point, and if Controller is the answer, then I'm not upset...but still, there is part of me that feels "guilty" writing the same instantiation process in several places. No? In the same way, I have my views set up so that to add form fields that would reflect the new table change would require a change in only a single file.

Comment: I agree with you on that front, however I believe if you're performing the same operation on one particular entity in multiple different places you have a bigger problem.  Odds are the actions are fundamentally different if you've structured your application properly.

Comment: If you're building entities in the controller then it sounds like you don't need a separate repository class.

Comment: The repository does more than just create an instance of an object.  My repositories are responsible for all CRUD operations involved in persisting data by interfacing with a data access object (DAO).  My repositories know how to split up my objects (a user versus its permissions, since they're saved separately but permissions don't exist on their own as first class objects).  They also take data from the DAO and turn it into a valid object.  I wouldn't want any of that in my controllers.